# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::title()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to implement a search so that user can input a book's title and laravel will browse the database and display results that match any character.

My 'book' table contains a 'title' field.

However if I input for example 'f' I get:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::title()

Search blade:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title')

@section('content')
    <h1>Search for books</h1>
    <form action="{{url('details')}}" method="POST">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div>
            <input type='text'  name='book' placeholder='Enter any character' />
        </div>
    <input type="submit" name="submitBtn" value="Search">
    </form>
@endsection
```

Details = Result page:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title')

@section('content')
    <h1>User Details</h1>
      <form>
      <p>
    <ul>
      @foreach ($books as $book)
    <a href=  "{{url('reader/'.$book->title)}}">
      {{$book->title}}</a>
      </p>
</form>
@endforeach
    </ul>
@endsection
```

Controller:

```
    function search()
    {
        $books = Book::all();
        return view('layouts/search',['books' => $books]);
    }
        function details() {
            $searchTerms = explode(' ', \Request::input('book'));
            $books = Book::whereHas('title', function($query) use($searchTerms) {
                if(!empty($searchTerms)){
                for

each($searchTerms as $book) {
               $query->where('book', 'LIKE', '%'. $book .'%');
            }          
         }
         })->first();
            return view('layouts/details', compact('book'));
}
```

Updated::

```
    function search()
    {
        $books = Book::all();
        return view('layouts/search',['books' => $books]);
    }
        function details() {
            $searchTerms = explode(' ', \Request::input('book')); 
            $books = Book::where(function($q) use($searchTerms) {
            foreach ($searchTerms as $book) {
             $q->orWhere('title', '%'.$book.'%');
            }
        })->first();
        return view('layouts/details', compact('books'));
}
```

Comment: Your indentation is a mess. You're trying to call model column on query (before ending the query with `->get()` / -`>first()` / `->paginate()`) somewhere.

Comment: Either use `->get()` or `->paginate()` since you require a collection in your view. Also just debug with `dd($books);` before returning the view in order to check what is actually returned by the query.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `whereHas()` here, because it uses relation which you don't have. Looks like `title` is a column in the `books` table, so do this instead:

```
$books = Book::where(function($q) use($searchTerms) {
        foreach ($searchTerms as $title) {
             $q->orWhere('title', '%'.$title.'%');
        }
    })
    ->first();
```

It will work if `$searchTerms` in an array and you just need to find the first book.

Also, if you want to search by full title you could just use `whereIn()`:

```
$books = Book::whereIn('title', $searchTerms)->first();
```

Comment: I have modified my controller and now I get: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laraveladvweb\resources\views\layouts\details.blade.php)

Comment: @Przemek check contents of `$searchTerms` with `dd($searchTerms)`. If it's empty, just wrap my code with something like `if (!empty($)) {}`. Do not check it inside the `where()` closure.

Comment: array:1 [▼
  0 => "f"
] so I do get the output

Comment: @Przemek the array looks fine, check your code again.

Comment: I have only modify the controller, please check my updated controller in the question